# OpenMPI spawn, scatter and gather

Tags: c

I'm new in `openMPI` using the programming language c, i have used the function `MPI_SPAWN()` to spawn other processes from the  master to the workers, also i used the functions `MPI_Gather()` & `MPI_Scatter()` to divide an array and send it to the workers and gather the result from them.

the result seems like :

```
the rank : 2 

the rank : 3 

0 0 0 0

the rank : 0 

0 1073741824 0 1073741824

0 -1879048192 0 -1879048192 

the rank : 1 

0 -1073741824 0 -1073741824
```

Here is my code :

Master :

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int rank,n_spawns = 4;
    int *msg = malloc(sizeof(int)* n_spawns*4);
    int *msg1 = malloc(sizeof(int)* n_spawns*4);
    int *recvbuf = malloc(sizeof(int) * n_spawns);


    srand(0);
    for(int i=0;i<4*n_spawns;i++) {
        msg[i] = rand() % 20;
        printf("%d ", msg[i]);
    }


    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm intercomm;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_spawn("/Users/a/Desktop/Study/AAPCours/FirstOMPI/worker", 
    MPI_ARGV_NULL, n_spawns, MPI_INFO_NULL, 0, MPI_COMM_SELF, 
    &intercomm,MPI_ERRCODES_IGNORE);

    MPI_Scatter(msg, n_spawns, MPI_INT, &recvbuf, n_spawns, MPI_INT, 
    MPI_ROOT, intercomm);
    MPI_Gather(&recvbuf, n_spawns, MPI_INT, msg, n_spawns, MPI_INT, 0, 
    intercomm);
    for (int i = 0; i<4*n_spawns; i++) {
         printf("%d ", msg[i]);
    }

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
 }
```

Worker :

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    int rank , n_spawns = 4;
    int *msg = malloc(sizeof(int)* n_spawns*4);
    int *recvbuf = malloc(sizeof(int) * n_spawns);

    MPI_Comm intercomm;
    MPI_Comm_get_parent(&intercomm);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    printf("the rank : %d \n",rank);
    for(int i=0;i<n_spawns;i++) {
        printf("%d ", recvbuf[i]);
        recvbuf[i] = recvbuf[i] + 1;
    }
    printf("\n");
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Can someone help me please ?

Comment: what would you expect as result ?

Comment: I expect as a result : 
rank 0 -> 10 11 15 12

Comment: I expect as a result : 
rank 0 -> 10 11 15 12
rank 1 -> 1 1 10 17
rank 2 -> 18 1 14 0 
rank 3 -> 6 16 10 8 
Workers add one in each element that have been send to it and send it to the master, finally the master gather all data and display them as the following:
11 12 16 13 2 2 11 18 19 2 15 1 6 17 11 9....
thank u for your help !